# How can a column match a parent row height in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Given the following layout I am trying to make the `FlatButton` (right side button) match the row height. Using `Flexible` or `Expandable` widgets doesn't seem to solve the problem. Being able to fill the remaining space with the text Column is a requirement.

[image: flutter]

This is the code that translate to the image.

```
class UITest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 12.0, bottom: 12.0, top: 12.0, right: 6.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [Text('12'), Text('MAY'), Text('12')],
            ),
          ),
          Text('–'),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 6.0, bottom: 12.0, top: 12.0, right: 12.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [Text('12'), Text('MAY'), Text('12')],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Text(
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'),
                Text('Lorem')
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10.0,
          ),
          ButtonTheme(
            buttonColor: Colors.red,
            minWidth: 0.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/icons/location.png'),
                width: 30.0,
                height: 30.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: you would have to use FittedBox here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4Uehk3_wlY&vl=en

Comment: wrap your `FlatButton` with `SizedBox(height: double.infinity, child: ...)`

Comment: @Uni FittedBox is not working in this example for unknow reasons :(. If I try to wrap it around ButtonTheme or FlatButton.

Comment: @pskink Adding SizedBox makes my layout to expand to the screen height, I want the button to be the same height as the row.

Answer (score 1):

You can something like this,

Wrap it with an `IntrinsicHeight` to match the `Row`'s height, so that it is not overflowed.

```
body: IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            
            .....
            
            ButtonTheme(
              buttonColor: Colors.red,
              minWidth: 0.0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              child: FlatButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/icons/location.png'),
                width: 30.0,
                height: 30.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

Refer: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html

Hope that solves your issue!

Comment: I don't want to hardcode the Container height, it should be dynamic.

Comment: This solution works great. However will try to achieve this without IntrinsicHeight, since is an expensive widget and this layout will be build in a listview.

Answer (score 0):

```
class UITest extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    // use container or similar widget as child for body
    body: Container(
    child:Row(
      // and this gives the children full height
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 12.0, bottom: 12.0, top: 12.0, right: 6.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [Text('12'), Text('MAY'), Text('12')],
          ),
        ),
        Text('–'),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 6.0, bottom: 12.0, top: 12.0, right: 12.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [Text('12'), Text('MAY'), Text('12')],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          // same here, use container as child
          child: Container(
            child:Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Text(
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'),
                Text('Lorem')
              ],
            )
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10.0,
        ),
        ButtonTheme(
          buttonColor: Colors.red,
          minWidth: 0.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/icons/location.png'),
              width: 30.0,
              height: 30.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
  ),
);
 }
}
```

Comment: This solution makes my layout height match the screen, I want the ButtonTheme/FlatButton be the same height as the parent Row.

Comment: in this case, change the height of the Container